# Get an ActiveModel::Serializer instance for an arbitrary (type unknown) model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, active-model-serializers

If I have an instance of a Project model and I want to serialize it into an arbitrary hash using active_model_serializer, I can do this:

```ruby
render :json => {:foo => "bar", :model => ProjectSerializer.new(my_project).as_json}
```

But in my scenario, I don't know the type of my model instance ahead of time so I need to determine the right serializer polymorphically. Poking around the active_model_serializer code, I see internally it uses `ActiveModel::Serializer.serializer_for` but this isn't callable from a controller for some reason. I can make it work like this:

```ruby
begin
   serializer = Object.const_get "#{model.name}Serializer"
   object_hash = serializer.new(model).as_json
rescue NameError
   object_hash = model.as_json
end
```

This works fine, but I'd rather my code not concern itself with this detail of the serializer. Is there a "right" way to find the serializer for an arbitrary model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
model_instance.active_model_serializer
```

I am not sure why this is not documented but it is in the code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 5 (ActiveModelSerializers 0.10) You can use `ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(model_instance)` and then call `#serializable_hash` or `#to_json` on that. More details are available in the readme: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/655c721d0d18988be795d767797cdcddc5369a87/README.md